# Python. Привести в нормальный вид Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, коллекции, counter

С помощью Counter (модуль collections) посчитали количество каждого типа символов по "столбикам" в списке с элементами, каждый элемент представляет собой строку из букв и символов (в моём случае чередование "a", "c", "g", "t", "-"). В каждой строке 200 символов.

Из этого

```
['agtcgtcgatcgatcgatcga----', 
 'aaagggtctgcgatgcgaattagca', 
 'gcgatcgtggcg-----cgggcggg']

lst = ['agtcgtcgatcgatcgatcga----', 'aaagggtctgcgatgcgaattagca','gcgatcgtggcg-----cgggcggg']

r = [collections.Counter(ar) for ar in zip(*lst)]

Print ('\n'.join(str(value) fro value in r))
```

Получили это (поставил количество рандомно):

```
Counter ({'a':2, '-':1, 'c':3})

Counter ({'t':3, '-':1, 'g':1})

Counter ({'a':2, '-':31, 'c':3})

и тд.
```

А мне нужно чтобы получилось примерно так (количество также рандомно поставил):

```
1: a=2, g=1, c=0, t=0, -=0
2: a=1, g=1, c=1, t=0, -=0
3: a=0, g=0, c=3, t=0, -=0
...
200. a=2, g=1, c=0, t=0, -=4
```

Либо хотя бы так (главное, чтобы было видно номер позиции в начале):

```
1. ({'a':2, '-':1, 'c':3})

2. ({'t':3, '-':1, 'g':1})

3. ({'a':2, '-':31, 'c':3})

и тд.
```

Comment: Непонятно, что должно получится. К примеру, что означает ``a=2`` в первой строчке желаемого результата?

Comment: Вы можете изменить заголовок вопроса таким образом, чтобы он соответствовал задаче и чтобы он мог помочь другим с похожей задачей найти данный вопрос?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно задать список полей и по ним составлять результат:

```
lst = ['agtcgtcgatcgatcgatcga----', 'aaagggtctgcgatgcgaattagca', 'gcgatcgtggcg-----cgggcggg']

from collections import Counter
rows = [Counter(ar) for ar in zip(*lst)]

for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    row_values = [row.get(x, 0) for x in 'agct-']
    print('{}: a={}, g={}, c={}, t={}, -={}'.format(i, *row_values))
```

Консоль:

```
1: a=2, g=1, c=0, t=0, -=0
2: a=1, g=1, c=1, t=0, -=0
3: a=1, g=1, c=0, t=1, -=0
4: a=1, g=1, c=1, t=0, -=0
5: a=0, g=2, c=0, t=1, -=0
...
```

---

Можно замудриться и сделать формат вывода гибким:

```
...
FIELDS = 'agct-'

for i, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    row_values = [row.get(x, 0) for x in FIELDS]
    row_text = ', '.join('{}={}'.format(name, value) for name, value in zip(FIELDS, row_values))
    
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, row_text))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = 'agtcgtcgatcgatcgatcga----',\
      'aaagggtctgcgatgcgaattagca',\
      'gcgatcgtggcg-----cgggcggg'

r = [collections.Counter(ar) for ar in zip(*lst)]

for n, cntr in enumerate(r, 1):
    print(n, dict(cntr))  # вывод номера (начиная с 1) и словаря
```